# What is the function of commas (쉼표) in the following sentences?

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrase-meaning

I have the following 2 paragraphs:

> 요즈음 세계 곳곳에서 서서히 일어나고 있는 ‘슬로푸드(slow food)’ 운동도 생활
> 습관 병을 고치는 데 도움이 된다. 자기 나라에서 오랫동안 **내려온,** 자기 민족의 전통 음식을 즐기
> 는 슬로푸드 운동을 통해 현대인들도 많은 병을 고칠 수 있을 것이다.

and

> 요즘은 기업, 부자 중심의 ‘거액 기부 문화’가 다수가 참여하는 ‘소액 기부 문화’로 바뀌는 추 세다. 이를 위해 가정과 학교,직장,사회 전반에 걸쳐 자선적 기부의 의미와 실천에 대한 교육이 이 뤄져야 한다. 이는 우리 국민이 건강한 시민으로 거듭날 수 **있는,** 그리고 건강한 사회를 만들기 위한 필수적인 요소이다.

I don't understand what is the function of commas(쉼표) in the above paragraphs? What does it add meaning to? Can you help me understand it? Thanks (sorry for my bad English)

Comment: It is separating two parts of the first half of a sentence that share a common second half: (자기 나라에서 오랫동안 내려온, 자기 민족의 전통 음식을 즐기는) 슬로푸드 운동을 통해 현대인들도 많은 병을 고칠 수 있을 것이다. ; 이는 (우리 국민이 건강한 시민으로 거듭날 수 있는, 건강한 사회를 만들기 위한) 필수적인 요소이다

Comment: @ user17915: Now i understanded. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 자기 나라에서 오랫동안 내려온, 자기 민족의 전통 음식을 즐기는 슬로푸드 운동을 통해 현대인들도 많은 병을 고칠 수 있을 것이다.

If you don't put a comma, it might be read like [자기 나라에서 오랫동안 내려온] 자기 민족의 전통 음식을 즐기는 슬로푸드 운동, with the bracketed part modifying 자기 민족.

But the actual meaning is [자기 나라에서 오랫동안 내려온], [(그리고) 자기 민족의 전통 음식을 즐기는] 슬로푸드 운동.  The two adjectival clauses modify 슬로푸드 in parallel, and the comma makes this more apparent.

In English, it would be

> the movement of slow food [which has passed down over a long time in your country] and [which appreciates your own country's traditional foods].

Similarly,

> 이는 [우리 국민이 건강한 시민으로 거듭날 수 있는], [그리고 건강한 사회를 만들기 위한] 필수적인 요소이다.
> = This is indispensable [to the nation's citizenry attaining good health once and for all], [and (thus) to bringing about a wholesome society].

Comment: Great answer. Now i understanded. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hmm... I think 자기 나라에서 오랫동안 내려온 should modify 전통 음식, because intuitively speaking, it seems weird to talk about 자기 나라에서 오랫동안 내려온 슬로푸드 운동. Can you think of a country that has a long history of "Slow Food Movement(TM)"?

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that too and almost gave two different interpretations but stopped short to make it simple.  The sentence is a bit flawed in this sense, but we can perhaps gloss over it by interpreting 슬로푸드 운동 as simply eating slow instead of an 운동 in the second case (traditionally people ate more slowly than now). When I answered it I thought 자기 나라에서 오랫동안 내려온 전통 음식 was not the smartest phrasing either because 자기 나라에서 오랫동안 내려온 is the very definition of 전통 (음식), which makes it somewhat redundant.  Anyway, on second thought your way might be more logical and I should have picked that one.

Comment: Definitely agree with you that the sentence should have been phrased better... :)